# How get one top numeric id from a table and date

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this code:

```
SELECT TYPE, BASE_ID, PART_ID, CREATE_DATE 
FROM WORK_ORDER 
WHERE CREATE_DATE >'17-NOV-2016' AND WAREHOUSE_ID ='MEX-04'
```

and it gives as results:
[image]

I would like to have only one of the `base_id` per `part_id`

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Also, how should we know which `base_id` to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Assuming this from your explanation.

```
SELECT TYPE, Max(BASE_ID) BASE_ID, PART_ID, CREATE_DATE 
FROM WORK_ORDER 
WHERE CREATE_DATE >'17-NOV-2016' AND WAREHOUSE_ID ='MEX-04'
Group By Type, Part_ID, Create_Date
```

**Updated** based on your new query... Try this. Assuming SQL Server.

```
SELECT PART.ID ,PART.USER_10 ,PART.USER_1 ,WORK_ORDER.STATUS 
,SUM (CASE when (OPERATION.RESOURCE_ID = '121-ADD') THEN OPERATION.RUN ELSE 0 END) "121-ADD" 
FROM PART
JOIN WORK_ORDER ON PART.ID = WORK_ORDER.PART_ID
JOIN OPERATION  ON WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
Where  
OPERATION.WORKORDER_TYPE ='M' 
AND  --(NewCode here) 
 OPERATION.RUN >0 AND WORK_ORDER.WAREHOUSE_ID ='MEX-04' 
AND WORK_ORDER.TYPE ='W' AND PART.FABRICATED ='Y' 
AND WORK_ORDER.CREATE_DATE >'17-NOV-2016' 
GROUP BY PART.ID ,PART.USER_10 ,PART.USER_1 ,WORK_ORDER.STATUS
```

Comment: Thanks WEI_DBA, this fixed our problem.

Comment: WEI, when trying to add that code to my code here, it does not work as I thought, can you take a look at It?

Comment: SELECT
PART.ID
  ,PART.USER_10
  ,PART.USER_1
  ,WORK_ORDER.STATUS
,SUM (CASE  when (OPERATION.RESOURCE_ID = '121-ADD') THEN OPERATION.RUN ELSE 0 END) "121-ADD"       
FROM
   PART, WORK_ORDER , OPERATION 
Where
WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
AND OPERATION.WORKORDER_TYPE ='M'
AND PART.ID = WORK_ORDER.PART_ID --(NewCode here)
AND OPERATION.RUN >0
AND WORK_ORDER.WAREHOUSE_ID ='MEX-04' 
AND WORK_ORDER.TYPE ='W'
AND PART.FABRICATED ='Y'
AND WORK_ORDER.CREATE_DATE >'17-NOV-2016'
GROUP BY
PART.ID
  ,PART.USER_10
  ,PART.USER_1
  ,WORK_ORDER.STATUS

Comment: What are you getting for results? Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This JOIN seems strange... `WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID`. Please verify.

Comment: I have 3 tables, 1) work_order, 2) operation, 3) part) WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID is the same data but WORK_ORDER.PART_ID  are duplicated sin ce WORK_order.base_id (This is numeric) is different, so I need only one WORK_order.base_id (top one) and I will get only one WORK_ORDER.PART_ID